# Java object creation difference

Tags: java, oop, object-create

I'm new to OOP concepts in Java. What is the difference between these two incidents?

1.

```
ClassName obj_name = new ClassName();
obj_name.method();
```

2.

```
new ClassName().method();
```

A good explanation is much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: The difference is the variable on the left side that stores the reference to `ClassName`...

Comment: @KevinEsche : Thanks mate

Answer (score 6):

In Option(1), you are still having/holding the reference to the object, so you can reuse that reference to access/call the other members(method/variables) of the object (class).

In Option (2), you don't have the reference (i.e., reference has been lost), so you will NOT be able to use it again.

One point to remember is that **if you want to access the same object members multiple times, you need to hold the reference (use option 1 above)**, rather than creating the object (option 2) again and again (which is costly operation i.e., occupies memory).

Please refer the below link for more details:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/usingobject.html

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Helps a lot1

Answer (score 0):

The reference variable `obj_name` hold the object of `ClassName`.through which you can call the instance method of ClassName through reference variable `obj_name`.

Whene ever we create an object and dont assign its reference to any reference variable its Known as Anonymous object instantiation.The Advantage of this type of instantiation is that you can only do the limited operation on that.Like you can call a single method.
If you want to perform mopre operation then reference varaibale which hold the object is better approach.If you have multiple method in your class and you want to use them then option 1 is right choice.

for details please go through this [Link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/usingobject.html)

Answer (score 0):

- in **option 1** you are creating an object with **new** keyword
  followed by constructor and that object is referenced by **class_name
  obj_name** variable so obj_name is pointing to that object.
- In **option 2** you not referencing to that object. just you make an
  object and call the method with no references so that object is
  eligible for garbage collection.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

While they might accomplish the same objective for the first call, the two approaches do fundamentally different things in terms of class definition and instantiation.

```
ClassName object = new ClassName();`
object.method();`
```

This is a case of instantiation. You create a new ClassName object which possesses certain instance fields and methods. It can call these methods, and the result may cause its instance fields to change.

```
ClassName.method();
```

On the other hand, this approach does not create an instance of the class. Instead, it calls `method` as a class attribute. Thus, the result can change fields in ClassName, but it won't necessarily existing fields in already-instantiated objects.

```
public class ClassName(){
    public int attr = 0;
    public ClassName(){}

    public void setAttr(int value){
        this.attr = value;
    }

    public void method(int value){
        this.attr += value;
    }
}
```

Now, using the first approach, we can create a `newObj` and call `newObj.method(100)`. This will increase `newObj`'s instance variable `attr` by 100.

To see the difference between the two approaches, let's use `setAttr(200)` to change the object's `attr` to 200.

Next, if we just use `ClassName.method(100)`, the class's `attr` value will become 100 for all future instances of ClassName. So if we create `ClassName nextObj = new ClassName()`, this new instance of ClassName will have `attr` of 100, while `newObj` will still have `attr` of 200.

Hopefully this explains the core difference between the two approaches.